# How to use string variables

Tags: java

I have been trying to figure out how to analyze wether an inputed variable is a number or a phrase, and then output an appropriate response.

```
System.out.println("Enter the number of lines in your triangle and pyramid");
lines = input.nextInt();
if (lines != int)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: take input as string and then use matches

Answer (score 1):

`Scanner` requires you to check the kind of input it sees *before* you call the `nextXyz` method.

> `if (lines != int)`

Once you call `nextInt()`, it is too late to check what kind of input you have: in order for `nextInt` to succeed, there *must* be an `int` available at the current point; otherwise an exception would be thrown.

Use `hasNextInt` method to check what you have at the current point in the input buffer:

```
if (input.hasNextInt()) {
    lines = input.nextInt();
} else {
    System.out.println("Please enter a number");
    input.nextLine(); // Drop the current input up to the end-of-line marker
}
```